# make a bounding box that are select an area in the leaflet map using leaflet-area-select

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular10, angular-leaflet-directive

I have an angular component and I want to use

```
leaflet-area-select
```

I import it and install it but when I call it in the code it's returning :

`Property 'areaSelect' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/Users/DELL/Desktop/New folder (2)/IR-Project/frontend/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'`

I do this :

```
import * as leaflet from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-area-select';


private initMap(): void {

    // Initialising map with center point by using the coordinates
    // Setting initial zoom to 3
    this.map = leaflet.map('map', {
      center: [ 39.8282, -98.5795 ],
      zoom: 3,

    });


    // Initialising tiles to the map by using openstreetmap
    // Setting zoom levels
    const tiles = leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 28,
      minZoom: 0,
    });

    // Adding tiles to the map
    tiles.addTo(this.map);
    
    // Initialize the area select plugin
    this.areaSelect = leaflet.areaSelect();

  // Add the area select layer to the map
    this.areaSelect.addTo(this.map);
    }
```

This part :

```
    this.areaSelect = leaflet.areaSelect();
```

not working and have a compiler error, red underline

what I should do and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the follow: You build your project. Then (inside the libs build directory) use `npm link`. Go inside your project and use `npm link leaflet` (if leaflet the correct name). Done. Now you can import the package in your angular project.

Or you can publish your lib to npm and install it the common way: `npm install xxx -s`

[Here](https://dgtechboost.com/2022/03/20/test-and-debug-angular-library-using-npm-link/) is only one good link. Search for **angular npm link**